# react - add to the same localStorage from two different components

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have two different components that show different categories of food and trying to implement a save button for both of them using localStorage.
I have this code on both of them

```
const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);

  const AddtoMenu = (e,selectedItem) => {
    let newMenu;
    if (menu.includes(selectedItem)) {
      // If the item is already in the array, remove it
      newMenu = menu.filter(item => item !== selectedItem);
    } else {
      // If the item is not in the array, add it
      newMenu = [...menu, selectedItem];
    }
    setMenu(newMenu);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('menu', JSON.stringify(menu));
  }, [menu]);
```

What happens now is that they don't share the same storage, they replace each other depending on the last item I saved.. how can I make both of them add to the last added item?

Comment: Your state is not being shared. You are initializing again in each component when you do `const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);`. You need to share the state as @CertainPerformance said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the state and state setter in a component that's an ancestor to both, and pass it down to both children.

```
const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
const addToMenu = (e,selectedItem) => {
  // ...
};
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('menu', JSON.stringify(menu));
}, [menu]);

return (
  <div>
    <Child1 {...{ menu, addToMenu }} />
    <Child2 {...{ menu, addToMenu }} />
  </div>
);
```

```
const Child1 = ({ menu, addToMenu }) => {
  // etc
```

If `setMenu` is used in the children outside of `addToMenu`, you can pass that down as well.